# The ServiceClass object does not implement the required method in the following form: OMElement add(OMElement e)

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am unable to figure out where the error is occurring. I checked my `Axis2.xml` and I have installed the latest Axis2 API. I am currently using Apache Tomcat 8 and JDK 1.8 for development.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The ServiceClass object does not implement the required method in the following form: OMElement add(OMElement e)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:508)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:368)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:414)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
    at com.test.axis2.AddOperatorStub.add(AddOperatorStub.java:181)
    at com.test.axis2.client.AddClientApp.main(AddClientApp.java:29)
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some extra info about what do you do and what do you want to do (some code snippet, when/where this error occours, etc.)

Comment: Hi I am trying to run a sample web service application. I have created the server and I am exposing the service using my client to run a simple method to add 2 nos. But instead it is throwing this error. I have used this link to create my application. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgY0pLadraE . I am able to the most part except the last part wherein I have to run as a Java Application.

Comment: There is a problem with your AddOperatorStub.add(). Do you pass two integers or an object into this method?

Comment: Yeah I did. I finally figured out that in Axis2.xml we need to add  <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only"                   class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
           <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"
class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" />

Comment: This snippet to make it work. I am not sure why this is important instead of default <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah I did. I finally figured out that in Axis2.xml we need to add

`<messageReceiver mep="w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only"; class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" /> <messageReceiver mep="w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"; class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" />`

This snippet to make it work. I am not sure why this is important instead of default

`<messageReceiver mep="w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only"; class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOnlyMessageReceiver"/> <messageReceiver mep="w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"; class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>`.

Thanks everyone for your prompt replies. Really helped me a lot to figure out what had to be done.

Comment: I concur... in my case the default message receivers were commented out and ONLY 1 proprietary in-out receiver was defined in the services.XML.  Doing the above (adding default and proprietary message receivers) solved my problem.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue

I solved it by updating WSDL Version as follows

http://www.w3.org/**2004/08**/wsdl/in-only  --> http://www.w3.org/**ns**/wsdl/in-only

&

http://www.w3.org/**2004/08**/wsdl/in-out  --> http://www.w3.org/**ns**/wsdl/in-out

**Example services.xml**

*Earlier*

```
<service name="Axis2HelloWorld" >
    <Description>
        Please Type your service description here
    </Description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
        <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.ciber.webservices.Axis2HelloWorld</parameter>
</service>
```

*New*

```
<service name="Axis2HelloWorld" >
    <Description>
        Please Type your service description here
    </Description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
        <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.ciber.webservices.Axis2HelloWorld</parameter>
</service>
```

Comment: so is it the problem with the wsdl version ? I haven't been able to figure out the real issue here

Comment: As other answer states you also need to add all the messageReceivers in the axis2.xml file

Answer (score 10):

Faced the same issue. Made the below change to the WEB-INF->services->MyService -> META-INF -> services.xml

**From:**

```html
<messageReceivers>
  <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
  <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</messageReceivers>
```

**To:**

```html
<messageReceivers>
  <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
  <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</messageReceivers>
```

Comment: It's the same with other answer

Answer (score 0):

Setting of message receivers did not work for me any more with 'Axis 1.8.2', so  solution was also to set the namespaces:

```
<service name="MyService" targetNamespace="http://service">

    <schema schemaNamespace="http://service"/>

    <messageReceivers>
       <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
       <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
```